# Как два контейнера Docker передают данные между собой по сети bridge?

Tags: docker

Объясните пожалуйста, ***без упоминания docker-compose***, на пальцах, как один контейнер обращается к другому в своей подсети (по сети bridge). Вопрос наверно про то как устроены сети (а может и нет).

Я понимаю, что приходит запрос на хост сервера на определенный порт. Этот порт хоста подвязан под порт контейнера (контейнер_1 см. дальше). Мы попадаем в *контейнер_1* (допустим backend), а затем обращаемся в *контейнер_2* (допустим база данных, какой-нибудь postgresql) из *контейнер_1*.

Понимаю, что мы коннектимся к БД с определенными переменными окружения (DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME и т.д.). Но, что это нам дает в данном случае не понимаю.

**По какому принципу *контейнер_1* обращается в *контейнер_2*?**

**UPD:**
А как контейнер_1 знает про существование контейнера_2? И как он понимает, что именно контейнеру_2 нужно передать данные?

Comment: два контейнера передают данные при помощи протоколов, например, tcp, поверх которого у http или любой другой

Comment: Кроме портов есть ещё ip-адреса, у каждого контейнера свой ip-адрес

Comment: А как контейнер_1 знает про существование контейнера_2? И как он понимает, что именно контейнеру_2 нужно передать данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изоляции сетей в контейнерах используются неймспейсы - отдельно работающие сетевые подсистемы ядра. Чтоб соединить неймспейс контейнера с нейспейсом хоста используют пары veth . это такой драйвер который создает две сетевые карты. То что влетело в один порт - вылетает из другого как есть. Один из этих интерфейсов помещается в неймспейс контейнера, а второй в бридж на хосте. Таким образом создается виртуальный провод между системами.

Таким образом путь пакета такой: маршрутизация в одном контейнере, запись в veth1b, выход из veth1a , форвард в бридже или/и маршрутизация на хосте, запись в veth2a, выход в контейнере из veth2b , маршрутизация в контейнере 2.

На привязанные порты к хосту трафик идти не должен при работе контейнеров между собой и правильной настройке.

Порты хоста нужны для работы с внешней сетью и сокрытия структуры внутренней сети контейнеров. Там работает специальная программа которая слушает порт и проксирует соединение во внутреннюю сеть контейнеров.

Контейнеры узнают адреса друг друга через DNS и файлы /etc/hosts которые им подсовывает докер насильно.

Comment: Это наверно то, что я хотел.
Благодарю!